# YEARWEEK() in Oracle10g?

Tags: oracle10g, sql-date-functions, to-char

In MySql I can use YEARWEEK() to receive the week and the related year of this week in one string. (E.g. `SELECT YEARWEEK('1987-01-01');` which leads to "198653").

Is there anything like that in Oracle10g?

I only know about the TO_CHAR function. But if I use `TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYYIW');` I receive 198753 and not 198653. So, how I am able to calculate this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does using `IYYYIW` format with `TO_CHAR()` make any difference? Note the "**I**" in the beginning instead of first "Y", it is for 4-digit year based on the ISO standard.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your example that Oracle returns 198753.

`select TO_CHAR(DATE '1987-01-01', 'YYYYIW') from dual` returns `198701` for me which is correct according to the ISO definition of week numbers.

Oracle has another format mask `WW` (instead of `IW`) that uses the week where the first day of the year is in as week #1 - which again would return week number 1 for the January 1st.

Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week_number#Week_numbering

I find MySQL's week number a bit strange actually, because no week numbering scheme I know would return week 53 for January 1st, 1987 (but that doesn't mean very much though...)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the wrong year number. Try 1988 instead of 1987.

Comment: Check out ain's answer. `TO_CHAR(DATE '1988-01-01', 'IYYYIW')` returns what you want